# Count files in a directory while excluding others by directory and subdirectories using PHP

Tags: php, file, count, directory

I have implemented a file-counting code using a function found here at SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/640944/2554788.

The function goes thus:

```
function getFileCount($path) {
    $size = 0;
    $ignore = array('.','..','cgi-bin','.DS_Store');
    $files = scandir($path);
    foreach($files as $t) {
        if(in_array($t, $ignore)) continue;
        if (is_dir(rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . $t)) {
            $size += getFileCount(rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . $t);
        } else {
            $size++;
        }   
    }
    return $size;
}
```

It works well, until I want to **exclude certain directories and all their contents**. What I need is to pass:

```
$ignore = array('.','..','cgi-bin','.DS_Store', 'SPECIAL_DIR');
```

At the moment, this function omits "SPECIAL_DIR", but seems to count all its content files, since they do not textually match "SPECIAL_DIR"!

I've bumped into a couple of solutions here and elsewhere that are meant to exclude files by path, but I haven't found one focused on recursively **counting** files (**not listing them** or anything else).

Thanks all.

Comment: What does `since they do not textually match "SPECIAL_DIR"` mean? Do you mean it counts the files inside SPECIAL_DIR when that's the entry point? Can you provide an explicit example?

Comment: The function excludes filenames (and directory names) if their name matches the provided exclusion array. What I need is to exclude any file or directory whose `path` matches any of the exclusion criteria. Kindly take a look at the answer I just provided.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this from the user-contributed section in PHP Manual. Credit to carneiro at isharelife dot com dot br

```
function directoryToArray($directory, $recursive = true, $listDirs = false, $listFiles = true, $exclude = '') {
         $arrayItems = array();
         $skipByExclude = false;
         $handle = opendir($directory);
         if ($handle) {
             while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
             preg_match("/(^(([\.]){1,2})$|(\.(svn|git|md))|(Thumbs\.db|\.DS_STORE))$/iu", $file, $skip);
             if($exclude){
                 preg_match($exclude, $file, $skipByExclude);
             }
             if (!$skip && !$skipByExclude) {
                 if (is_dir($directory. '/' . $file)) {
                     if($recursive) {
                         $arrayItems = array_merge($arrayItems, directoryToArray($directory. '/' . $file, $recursive, $listDirs, $listFiles, $exclude));
                     }
                     if($listDirs){
                         $file = $directory . '/' . $file;
                         $arrayItems[] = $file;
                     }
                 } else {
                     if($listFiles){
                         $file = $directory . '/' . $file;
                         $arrayItems[] = $file;
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         closedir($handle);
         }
         return $arrayItems;
  }
```

The function returns complete path listings. Exclusion is by regex passed into the function, and the file count comes from `count()`ing the returned array.

This seems to do the job, but I await any alternative answer on this, regarding stuff like code brevity and performance.