# Print all files and folders in a folder recursively

Tags: php, recursion

I want to list all files and folders in a folder recursively. I have written code to get the output, but i am not able to show in a proper nested manner.

```
   <?php


class CheckFolder{

    public function getSubFolders($dir)
    {
        $folders = array();
        $ffs = scandir($dir);
        foreach($ffs as $ff)
        {
            if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..')
            {
                if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff))  $folders[] = $ff;
            }
        }
        return $folders;      
    }

    public function getFiles($dir)
    {
        $files = array();
        if(is_dir($dir))
        {
            $ffs = scandir($dir);
            foreach($ffs as $ff)
            {
                if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..')
                {
                    if(!is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff))  $files[] = '<li>'.$ff.'</li>';
                }
            }
        }
        return $files;
    }    

    function listFolderFiles($dir)
    {
        $ffs     = scandir($dir);
        $folders = $this->getSubFolders($dir);
        $files   = $this->getFiles($dir);

        if(strpos($dir, '/') >0)
        {
            $folderName = substr($dir, strrpos($dir, '/') + 1);
        }
        else
        {        
            $folderName =   $dir;
        }
        echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li>'.$folderName.'</li>';
        if(count($files) > 0)
        {   
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach($files as $file)
            {
                // /echo '<li>'.$file.'</li>';
                echo $file;
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }

        echo '</ul>';

        foreach($folders as $folder)
        {
           // echo '<li>'.$folderName.'</li>';
            $this->listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$folder); 
        }

    }


}

$dir = 'test';
$folder = new CheckFolder();
$folder->listFolderFiles($dir)

?>
```

Current Output
[image]

Expected:

[image]

Comment: Call the function again inside itself if it is checked as child folder, this time passing the `foreach($pf as $f)` "`$f`" var as parameter. Don't forget to check inside foreach if the folder have children, because if not its leaf folder and a new array should not begin again. [See if it helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640931/recursively-counting-files-with-php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you have looked at, and possibly discounted, the built in [recursiveIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) and [recursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) set of classes?

The below does not take care of the indentation to which you refer but it is a great way ( although perhaps not as quick as a recursive function of your own making ) to iterate through all directories in a path.

The manual is sparse with good examples IMHO but the following might be of interest, especially as you can specify things like `CHILD_FIRST`.

```
$folder=__DIR__;
foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $folder, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME ), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST ) as $file => $info ) {
    if( $info->isFile() && $info->isReadable() && $info->isWritable() ){
        echo $info->getPathname() .' ' . $info->getFilename().BR;
    }
}
```