# Get folder count in PHP

Tags: php, while-loop

I am trying to build my own gallery script for various reasons but I'm stuck on trying to count the sub-directories of another directory.

The scheme is
categories

- Folder
  -- Folder1
  ----- some other folders
  -- Folder2 
  ----- some other folders 
  -- Folder3 
  ----- some other folders

I got as far as to link to show a list of Folder1 and Folder2 and Folder3 each one with links and all, but when I try to add the code for counting each sub-folder of F1, F2 and F3, I can't get it to work.

This is my code to display them

```
if( $handle = opendir('.') ) {
    $blacklist = array('.', '..', 'somedir', 'somefile.php', 'index.php');
    while( ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
        if (!in_array($file, $blacklist)) { 
            echo "<div class='catrow'>";
            echo "<span class='catlink'>";
            echo "<i class='fa-solid fa-star'></i>";
            echo "<a href='$file'>" .preg_replace('/_/', ' ', $file). "</a>";
            echo "</span>";
            echo "&rarr; This category has <b>". **COUNT NUMBER CODE GOES HERE** ."</b> albums";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    } 
    closedir ($handle);
}
```

I looked through various topics on here and links on the internet in general, the most of them work when not inside the while loop, but I need to work for each, so that any time a folder is created it automatically will count the folders inside.

Comment: See [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Comment: You need to open the subdirectory and loop through its contents to get the count of files.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, but I need to ask for an example. I'm all self-taught about this and I need to see a practical example to understand what you're saying. Please, and thanks.

Comment: @AlexHowansky That is one of those that worked outside but it counted too much and only outside the loop. It was 1500 files richer than I needed it to be and wouldn't exclude the .php files

Comment: `count(scandir($directory))` will return the number of items in `$directory`.

Comment: You should subtract 2 so you doin't count the `.` and `..` entries.

Comment: @Barmar I don't get where I should use that. Inside my code? Write another using scandir?

Comment: In place of `**COUNT NUMBER CODE GOES HERE**`

Comment: In this case `$directory` should be `$file`.

Comment: you also may need to use `if (is_dir($file))` if there can be regular files in`FolderN`.

Comment: @Barmar okay adding count(scandir) did generate two different numbers for two different directories but it's random. Like first one has a 5 (and inside there's 2 folders and one index.php file) and second one is empty but has a 2.
Inside each of Folder 1, Folder 2,... there will only be an index.php file and subfolders (that have images inside them) but I only wanna count the subfolders not the images and not the index.php

Comment: Did you see my comment about subtracting 2?

Comment: `scandir()` doesn't recurse into deeper subdirectories. If you need that count, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640931/recursively-counting-files-with-php

Comment: @Barmar I did see the comment about substracting but I don't think that simply adding -2 does the trick.
As for what I'm trying to do I just want each Folder I add in the Main Folder to count its sub-folders. Only that. Nothing deeper than that, just for it to tell me "okay you've 2 folders inside here"

Comment: Do you only want to count subfolders and not files? `scandir()` doesn't distinguish them, you'll need to write a loop that does that.

Comment: @Barmar okay if there was a way to distinguish and like write "This category has 2 albums and 125 files" that would be great, but otherwise yes just count the albums (subfolders)

Comment: There's nothing built-in that does that. You'll need to write your own code to count files and directories separately.

Comment: @Barmar then I'm just fine to count the subfolders, I don't know enough of php to write my own code. But even if scandir doesn't distinguish, right now it's giving me a value of 5 for a folder that has 2 sub-folders and one php file.

Comment: you still have to write your own code to do it, there's nothing automatic.

Comment: 2 sub-folders + 1 file + `.` + `..` = 5

Comment: @Barmar I figured what you meant by substract 2 and I got now 3 files in one folder (the one with 2 subfolders and one index.php) and 0 to the other that is actually empty.
So now I should figure how to exclude that index.php, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Hi! I'm glad you figured it out. Please note that this site likes to strictly separate Questions and Answers, so if you solve your own problem, you're encouraged to enter the details in the Answer box below, rather than editing the original question.

Comment: @Barmar I know it's tempting to be as helpful as possible with quick comments, but a lot of the above comments look like they belonged in an answer, which the OP could then have asked for further clarification on.

Comment: Lady C Please dont amend the question to include the answer. There is a place for answers and thats where people will look for it. If the quesiton has the answer in it it no longer has the question and Error.

Comment: And finally this question has a kind of solution already. The first comment from Alex Howansky should have led you in the right direction. Use iterators for a huge amount of data, because they are less memory consuming and faster then simple array iteration. Just go here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640931/recursively-counting-files-with-php#answer-640950. Combine it with a RecursiveFilterIterator in combination with RecursiveIteratorIterator: https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php#V114504 to filter out the dot dirs.

Comment: @IMSoP I didn't want to write the OP's code for them, which is what an answer would require.

Comment: @IMSoP sorry, was not sure which way to go cause I wasn't able to find a reply in help for it.

Comment: My solution: to add `count(array_diff(scandir($file), array('.', '..', 'index.php') ))` where I had written **COUNT NUMBER CODE GOES HERE**, which allows me to count the sub-directories inside the directory and exclude the index.php file inside it.

Comment: @LadyC No worries, I know it's different from how some sites work. Here's where the help centre talks about it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer