Count JPG files in sub-directories
So I have a series of directories, that contain other subdirectories that contain other subdirectories and so on to arrive to the .jpg files.
Now each subdirectory has a different number of subdirectories itself and I need the code to scan through the main and go through each and count the number of .jpg files, only those.
The structure is:
**MAIN DIRECTORY (Television)**

--**Subdirectory #1** 
---Subdirectory 
----Subdirectory 
-----jpg Files (*1*)

--**Subdirectory #2** 
---Subdirectory 
----Subdirectory
-----Subdirectory
------jpg Files (*114*)

This was my code to display the sub-directories of category "Television" and count the number of albums each has
$path    = '.'; 
$files = array_diff(scandir($path, 1), array('.', '..', 'index.php', 'error_log')); 
foreach(array_unique($files) as $file) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='catrow'>";
    echo "<div class='categories'>";
    echo "<span class='catlink'><a href='$file'>";
    echo preg_replace(array('/_/', '/--/', '/=/',), array(' ', '&#x27', '&#x3A '), $file). "</a>";
    echo "</span>";
    echo "<div class='albums-count'><span>";
    echo "This category has <b>" . count(array_diff(scandir($file), array('.', '..', 'index.php', 'error_log') )) . "</b> albums.";
    echo "</span></div>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td class='catrow' align='center'><span class='photos-count'><b>";
    echo ***FILES COUNT GOES HERE***
    echo "</b><br>photos</span></td>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}   

Browsing I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41848361/23556208 which at least seemed to be showing a number, not the right one though. And repeated in loop the same one.
How do I get this right?

The answer you linked to uses RecursiveDirectoryIterator. You're not doing that, so you don't recurse into subdirectories.

str_replace would perform better than preg_replace and you won't need delimiters. You aren't using regex so no need for regex function. Maybe running shell command to get count could achieve your goal? find . -type f -name "*.jpg" | wc -l on your sub-directory... or it would work from highest level too, I think you're trying to split between dirs and assume some are albums but not sure about that.

@user3783243 actually no that wouldn't work because then I wouldn't be able to display anything since the code will be looking for a folder without symbols where they in fact are and just generate errors.

@Barmar I knew I needed to use Recursive and went looking directly for that, however I don't know how to implement that into my code OR my code with that to get all I need, which is displaying the categories alphabetically (from newest to oldest), get inside them, display the number of subdirectories in them and total files counting into each of them.

scandir($file) needs to be scandir("$path/$file").  Why are you using array_diff() if you only want to count .jpg files?

There are a number of ways of achieving the result you want in the Q&A you reference. Try one/two/... until you get something that suits your situation

@RiggsFolly yeah it's been now 8 hours I've tried one/two/... and finally resorted to asking here.

Welcome to development! Thats what it is all about. Often Trial and Error until you get there

@Barmar those are two different things. That's not counting the files, that's counting the sub-directories into each

No it isn't. If you leave out $path/, it tries to refer to $file in the current directory, not the directory you're looping over in the foreach loop.

Instead of array_diff(), use array_filter() to filter the names to just the ones ending in .jpg.

@Barmar the code I have is working fine on 3 different sites, I don't need that fixed. I need to implement counting the files and nothing else. But thanks for the inputs.

This was my code to display the sub-directories of category "Television" Where is Television in the code?

Please show what you tried to recurse into subdirectories. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

@Barmar $path    = '.';  it's effectively listing them in order and from newest to oldest as I want them to.

Yeah, but it won't work when you go into nested subdirectories. Then you need to add the directory prefix.

@Barmar if I put ./. it gives a random number repeated in loop, if I put /Television it breaks the site
$dir = realpath('./.');     $objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(         new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir),         RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST     );     $count=iterator_count($objects); echo number_format($count);

$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
$regex = new RegexIterator($files, '/^.+(.jpg)$/i', RegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
$count=iterator_count($files);

$files = array_diff(scandir($path, 1), array('.', '..', 'index.php', 'error_log'));
foreach(array_unique($files) as $file) {...
 echo number_format($count);...
} ```

I got this far to manage and hide the "." and ".." from counting but it still repeats the same value ffor each and GET_MATCH doesn't work.

To count the total number of JPEG files recursively, one could use RecursiveIteratorIterator based on RecursiveDirectoryIterator and CallbackFilterIterator to filter only JPEG files, e.g.:
<?php
/**
 * Recursively count the number of JPEG files in a directory.
 *
 * @param string $directory The directory to search for JPEG files
 * @param int $depth The maximum depth. -1 means no limit.
 * @return int The number of JPEG files found.
 */
function countJpgFiles(string $directory, int $depth = -1): int
{
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
            $directory,
            FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS
            | FilesystemIterator::FOLLOW_SYMLINKS
        )
    );
    $files->setMaxDepth($depth);

    $jpgFiles = new CallbackFilterIterator(
        $files,
        fn (SplFileInfo $file): bool => isJpgFile($file)
    );

    return iterator_count($jpgFiles);
}

/**
 * Check if a file is a JPEG file.
 *
 * @param SplFileInfo $file The file to check
 * @return bool True if the file is a JPEG file, false otherwise.
 */
function isJpgFile(SplFileInfo $file): bool
{
    $extension = strtolower($file->getExtension());

    return $file->isFile() && ($extension === 'jpg' || $extension === 'jpeg');
}


To count the files in the subdirectories, list the top-level directories using DirectoryIterator or FilesystemIterator and count the JPEG files in each of them, e.g.:
<?php
/**
 * List the top-level directories in a directory.
 * @return iterable<SplFileInfo>
 */
function listTopLevel(string $directory): iterable
{
    $directories = new FilesystemIterator(
        $directory,
        FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS
        | FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO
        | FilesystemIterator::FOLLOW_SYMLINKS
    );

    foreach ($directories as $directory) {
        if ($directory->isDir()) {
            yield $directory;
        }
    }
}

$mainDir = './gallery/Television'; // TODO Change this to your top-level directory
$lineFormat = "%-30s%10d\n";
$prefix = '    ';

printf($lineFormat, "JPEGs in $mainDir", countJpgFiles($mainDir));
printf($lineFormat, "{$prefix}top-level", countJpgFiles($mainDir, 0));

foreach (listTopLevel($mainDir) as $subDir) {
    printf(
        $lineFormat,
        $prefix . $subDir->getPathname(),
        countJpgFiles($subDir->getPathname())
    );
}

Let's say we have the following directory structure:
gallery/Television
├── Sub1
│   ├── sub.jpg
│   ├── Sub-Sub1
│   │   ├── one.jpg
│   │   └── two.jpg
│   └── Sub-Sub2
│       ├── one.jpg
│       ├── sub-sub-two.jpg
│       └── two.jpg
├── Sub2
│   ├── sub.jpg
│   ├── Sub-Sub1
│   │   ├── one.jpg
│   │   ├── sub2sub-sub.jpg
│   │   └── two.jpg
│   └── Sub-Sub2
│       ├── one.jpg
│       ├── sub2sub-sub.jpg
│       ├── sub-sub-two.jpg
│       └── two.jpg
└── top-level.jpg

Then, the output of the script would be:
JPEGs in ./gallery/Television         15
    top-level                          1
    ./gallery/Television/Sub1          6
    ./gallery/Television/Sub2          8


Thanks but I understand 0 of all you said.
The first code, my program even tells me there's errors, like commas where shouldn't be and this line static fn (SplFileInfo $file): bool => isJpgFile($file), says that fn is expecting a ::
If I even try to just copy and paste and go from there (correcting the commas situation), it breaks the site and shows a blank page.
And $mainDir = './gallery/Television'; // TODO Change this to your directory
Change to what? That's the directory that should count the files inside each subdirectory.

Additionally, Television and top-level don't have .jpg files to count, they contain sub-directories to count and inside the sub-directories are other sub-directories with the images.

@LadyC, You seem to run an old version of PHP. The code in the answer assumes PHP 8. I've removed the static for fn and the trailing commas for the last arguments to make the code more 'portable' for you. The $mainDir should be substituted to your $path. If Television directory doesn't contain any jpg files, it's still not an issue, is it? I just wanted to show you the different ways to find the files, just use whatever is appropriate in your situation. By the way, your question is not very specific on how exactly you are trying to count the files: all of them or top-level sub-dirs?

I've also added more PHP doc blocks that I think should make the code more readable and easier to understand. If you have any specific questions about the code, feel free to ask.

it's really weird, I'm on PHP 8.1
$jpgFiles = new CallbackFilterIterator($files, fn(SplFileInfo $file): bool => isJpgFile($file)); this says unexpected $file (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')' not sure which $file it refers to though

@LadyC, apparently, the SPL extension is not enabled in your build.

another thing I don't have a proper answer for, honestly.
But I will say that while Dreamweaver flags an error in there, if I save and upload the file on the FTP the site doesn't break, so maybe it's irrelevant?
Anyways "listTopLevel" gets errors, maybe for a wrong maindir but I can't get the right one

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Temporary method that's working
echo count(glob($file. "*/*/*/*.{jpg}",GLOB_BRACE));

where each * represents how deep into that search it needs to go
